# How can I multipath BGP prefixes of equal AS-path length?

Tags: bgp

Say I have two routes of 10.0.0.0/8. One has an AS-path of 100 200 300, the other has 400 500 300. How can I make BGP install both routes into the FIB on a Cisco router?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cisco has a command that will do this although it's technically undocumented.

Within the the context of `router bgp <your AS>` you should enter `bgp best-path as-path multipath-relax`

This will cause it to multipath routes that satisfy the usual requirements (i.e. equal weight, MED and LocPref) but only requires the AS-path to be the same length rather than identical.

On a side note, there is also `bgp best-path as-path ignore` - unfortunately this **does not** permit multipathing regardless of AS path and will instead entirely prevent it.